# how to find random access file structure

Tags: random-access

Is there a way to programmatically determine the UDT structure of a "flat" Random Access (aka direct access) file that was created using a UDT?

To my knowledge there are no EOL characters or anything that could be used to mark data points but I'm hoping I'm wrong.

PB example

```
TYPE StudentRecord
  LastName     AS STRING * 20 ' A 20-character string
  FirstName    AS STRING * 15 ' A 15-character string
  IDnum        AS LONG        ' Student ID, a Long-integer
  Contact      AS STRING * 30 ' Emergency contact person
  ContactPhone AS STRING * 14 ' Their phone number
  ContactRel   AS STRING * 8  ' Relationship to student.
  AverageGrade AS SINGLE      ' Single-precision % grade
END TYPE

DIM Student AS StudentRecord

Student.LastName = "Anderson"
Student.FirstName = "Bob"
Student.IDnum = 494425610
Student.Contact = "Ma Anderson"
Student.ContactPhone = "(800) BOBSMOM"
Student.ContactRel = "Mother"
Student.AverageGrade = 98.9

PUT #fileNumber, recordNumber, Student
```

I want to programmatically find the structure of StudentRecord in this example.

Comment: The capability of random access - being able to seek to any location in the file and read/write there - and the concept of the structure of a file are completely orthogonal/unrelated concepts. As such, there's no way to answer this question as currently stated.

Comment: edited with more detail